# Windows 10 Multi-Desktop Feature Customization

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, multiple-desktop

**BACKGROUND**: I've been playing with the Windows 10 Multi-Desktop feature (Windows Button + Tab, then bottom right corner). I like the idea of it, however I dislike that I see in the taskbar for a given desktop, programs open in other desktop instances. E.g. in desktop `n` I have IntelliJ IDEA open, and in desktop `n + 1` I have Notepad open. When I'm working on desktop `n` and I look at the taskbar, I can see Notepad, even though it is not open in desktop `n`. I would prefer that my current desktop instance that I am working with (desktop `n`) is isolated from other instances (`n + 1` for example) so that I do not see programs open in those instances on my taskbar. Visual examples below.

[image: Desktop Instance with Taskbar showing]
In the above image, you can see the taskbar shows Google Chrome, IntelliJ IDEA, and Paint.net from left to right. Of these 3, only Chrome and Paint.net are open in this desktop instance I'm currently on. IntelliJ IDEA is open in another desktop instance, yet appears on the current desktop's taskbar (annoying to me).

In the following image, you can see that IntelliJ IDEA and Google Chrome are open in different desktops.
[image: Task View Screen With 2 Desktop Instances]

I would greatly prefer it if in the first picture, I did not see IntelliJ IDEA in the taskbar at all.

**QUESTION**: Is there a way to prevent programs open in other desktops from appearing in the taskbar of the desktop I'm currently working on?

Comment: Mine (Version 1607, Build 14393) works as you claim you want it to work.  Which version and build of Windows 10 are you using?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Version 1607, Build 14393.351

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 any idea how to get multidesktop thing to work?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 You're seriously gonna drop a question about my system, then just not come back after I answered your question? Is that how this site works?

Comment: I no longer require your assistance.